# Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0) Error: timeout of 0ms exceeded

Tags: react-native, axios

I want to show the total number of connections I have using the API I created, but when I run with the mobile project, the results show only '0' and show this error message. It should automatically display the number of connections on the screen, I already tested it with the web application and it works, the problem persists only in the mobile version. In the api.ts file the URL is in this format because I am simulating the mobile application on an iOS device with a DevTools connection through the Tunnel.

My api.ts for connetion with api

```
import axios from "axios";

const api = axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://y7-xkq.anonymous.mobile.exp.direct:3333",
});

export default api;
```

```
const [totalConnections, setTotalConnections] = useState(0);

    useEffect(() => {
        api.get("connections").then((response) => {
            // console.log(response);
            const { total } = response.data;

            setTotalConnections(total);
        });
    }, []);
```

```
<Text style={styles.totalConnections}>
    Total de {totalConnections} conexões já realizadas{" "}
    <Image source={heartIcon} />
</Text>
```

Comment: What object are you getting as response from the API?

Comment: Are you testing on android or iOS?

Comment: If you are using android, make sure that your device/emulator has access to the internet (using the browser) and that you have declared the android.permission.INTERNET permission into your Android Manifest

Comment: I'm testing on iOs cell phone... 
I defined 'total' as a const to get the answer, but I treated it as a state, so 'totalConnections' is the current value of the connections and 'setTotalConnections' is where the connection will be updated by the API with the parameter 'total' that seeks the updated answer. @RanderGabriel

Comment: In your web version you are using the same URL?

Comment: There is a relatively recent discussion about a similar problem. https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/2103